# Remix.run environment variables in Catch/Error Boundary

Tags: remix.run

In my remix.run Web-App there are different .env files, for each client there is one .env file. In these files I set the name of the client to show in my layout and as title in meta tag.

How can I access these env variables in CatchBoundary and ErrorBounday in `root.tsx`?

Since the website is rendered on the server there must be possibility to access environment variables in these Boundary functions I think.

What I don't want is to use nested boundaries by exporting these functions in every route redundantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the environment variables from the loader function.

Uncomment one of the options below:

```
export async function loader() {
  // Option 1: triggers CatchBoundary
  // throw new Response(
  //   JSON.stringify({
  //     message: "Not Found",
  //     ENV: {
  //       PRIMARY_COLOR: process.env.PRIMARY_COLOR,
  //     },
  //   }),
  //   {
  //     status: 404,
  //   }
  // );

  // Option 2: triggers ErrorBoundary
  throw new Error(
    JSON.stringify({
      message: "I am a failure!",
      ENV: {
        PRIMARY_COLOR: process.env.PRIMARY_COLOR,
      },
    })
  );
}
```

For the CatchBoundary:

```
export function CatchBoundary() {
  const caught = useCatch();
  const data = JSON.parse(caught.data);
  const PRIMARY_COLOR = data.ENV.PRIMARY_COLOR;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Caught</h1>
      <p>Status: {caught.status}</p>
      <pre style={{ color: PRIMARY_COLOR }}>
        <code>{JSON.stringify(data.message, null, 2)}</code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For the ErrorBoundary:

```
export function ErrorBoundary({ error }: { error: Error }) {
  const data = JSON.parse(error.message);
  const PRIMARY_COLOR = data.ENV.PRIMARY_COLOR;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Error</h1>
      <p style={{ color: PRIMARY_COLOR }}>{data.message}</p>
      <p>The stack trace is:</p>
      <pre>{error.stack}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This ErrorBoundary only works with errors that have a `message` with the correct JSON formatting. That means the app developer has to catch, wrap, and rethrow every possible exception they could encounter in the `loader`.